# Magento 2 automated testing

Tags: magento, testing, magento2, magento-2.0

I am a newbie of Magento 2, I have been learning it for 2 weeks. I have heard from some people there are some automated testing frameworks for Magento 2.

I have been trying this http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/mtf/mtf_introduction.html , but I have experienced some errors so far.

So I would like to get more guide for this, if you have any, please help me!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow below link run test for specific module

[Run tests for a specific module in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86579/run-tests-for-a-specific-module-in-magento2)

For  functional Test you can check below URL

[Functional Tests by Example for Magento2](http://store.fooman.co.nz/blog/functional-tests-by-example-for-magento2-mtf.html)